# angular 7 - reload data in data table

Tags: angular, datatable, refresh, rerender

I'm using angular 7 with angular-datatables.
I'm tring to define a "rerender" button in order to reload data [like in this example](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/advanced/rerender).

I don't understand what should I place in the render function:

**My API function:**

```
fn_getFavoriteTables() {

  this._getFavoriteTablesApiCall =  this.getFavoriteTablesService.getFavoriteTables(Number(localStorage.getItem('UserID')), Number(localStorage.getItem('BranchID'))).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroySubject$)).subscribe(x => {
        this.getFavoriteTables = x;
        this.dtTrigger.next();
    });

};
```

**rerender function:**

```
rerender(): void {
    this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
        // Destroy the table first 

        dtInstance.destroy();


        // Call the dtTrigger to rerender again
        this.dtTrigger.next();
    });
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  console.log('ngDestroy');
  // Do not forget to unsubscribe the event
  this.dtTrigger.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer that worked for me:
[this is the source site](https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy())

```
 rerender(): void {
    this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
        // Destroy the table first 
        //debugger;
        var table = $('#favoriteTable').DataTable();

        $('#tableDestroy').on('click', function () {
            table.destroy();
        });

        dtInstance.destroy();

        this.fn_getFavoriteTables();

    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This can also be done like this:

```
import { DataTableDirective } from 'angular-datatables';

dtElement: DataTableDirective;
dtInstance: Promise<DataTables.Api>;

rerender(): void  {
  this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
    dtInstance.ajax.reload()
  });
}
```

Comment: I have tried this solution but it cannot find the namespace DataTables.Api. I have imported DatatablesModule as well as types/datatablesnet and nothing... I]'m using version 9.0.2 of datatables

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DataTable destroy() API to remove the table and re-use the dtTrigger to render the table again. Please check below link.

https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/advanced/rerender